# Content of TxtBox1 Transferred To TxtBox2 Throwing Error Messages

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am writing a simple program to transfer the text written in 1 textbox to another textbox but the issue is that Visual Studio is throwing an exception and I am not able to understand what exactly is the problem. It states that the javascript functions have no definition which is not correct. Plz help!

Error Message:

Error 1   'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'txt1Transfer' and
   no extension method 'txt1Transfer' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default_aspx'
   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
   d:\ADO_NETprojects\ASP_Website_Practice\Default.aspx 30

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function txt2Transfer() {
        var str = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
        document.getElementById("txt2").value = str;

    }

    function txt1Transfer() {
        var str1 = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
        document.getElementById("txt1").value = str1;
    }
</script>
    </head>

        <body>
          <form id="form1" runat="server">
               <div>TextBox1
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" 
                        style="margin-left:30px; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px; 
                          Height="58px" TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                 <div>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn1" Text="tfr_1" runat="server" 
                     style="margin-left:95px;" onclick="txt1Transfer()"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn2" Text="tfr_2" runat="server" 
                     style="margin-left:15px;" onclick="txt2Transfer()"/>
                 </div>
                 <div>TextBox2
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" 
                    style="margin-left:30px; margin-top:20px;" Height="56px"  

                     TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                 </div>    
        </form>
       </body>

      </html>
```

Comment: Does it works for the other method ?  txt2Transfer()

Comment: @NetStarter No it doesn't work for anyone of the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OnClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of the asp:Button server-side control points to a server-side function (so in your .aspx.cs or .aspx.vb file, depending on what language you are using). Since you have not defined any function called txt1Transfer or txt2Transfer in your code-behind, the compiler is throwing an exception.

If you want to point to a Javascript function, you need to use the [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute instead.

So you code should become:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" Text="tfr_1" runat="server" style="margin-left:95px;" OnClientClick="txt1Transfer()"/>
<asp:Button ID="btn2" Text="tfr_2" runat="server" style="margin-left:15px;" OnClientClick="txt2Transfer()"/>
```